# Setting relationships in core data swift after context saved

Tags: swift, core-data

Working with a core data model and I am still new this. Right now I have a view controller that saves the relationship between 2 entities and it stays fine until I have to add another relationship into the primary core data entity. When I do this the relationship between the initial 2 relationships breaks and the tableview is no longer able to present the relationship and thus crashes. I know in order to set the relationship I need to insert it into the already existing context but how do I actually go about that without clearing out the previously set relationhip?

Let's say I have a entity named primary and one named secondary. The relationship between these two sets fine. When I try to set the relationship for the third entity the relationship between the secondary and primary clears out. The real problem is that I am actually passing the object I want to store the relationship into so when I do code similar to this:

```
passedObject?.relationhips = entity.relation
```

it isn't actually setting the relationship. Am I missing something? Do I have to insert something into the primary entity context outside of setting the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

A really common core data crash is when you've updated your model but the app on the simulator has data that uses the old model and crashes. So after updating your modal it's a good habit to delete your app from the simulator before running again (although I think Apple made a change in iOS9 where your app will migrate the data automatically but I've not checked that).

If that's not the problem it would help a lot to see a screen grab of your model to see how relationships between your entities are set up.

Because you're new to core data, I'd check to see if the relationship type if 'to one' (the default) or 'to many' (to use if you want a connection between a set of entities instead of just one).

Comment: I have it going primary going to many and secondary and third going to one. All that part of my app is setup correctly but this is strictly an issue of setting the relationship in the MOC t I am providing on the view controller recording additional information. When I try to establish the relationship between the object created on the third and the primary it doesn't store. passedObject is a variable containing the type of the primary entity. I know I have to set the relationship in both entities but when I try to call both ways it crashed. NSFaultingMutableSet unreconized selector

Comment: I tried deleting the app from the simulator but it doesn't seem to be the issue. The method I also tried was passedObject?relationships = entity.description then directly below it the entityInsert.relation = passedObject?.relatioinships but that just causes a different crash.

Comment: 'unreconized selector' makes me think that maybe you've just got a typo between your modal and the NSManagedObject subclass.

Comment: the full error is as follows unrcognized selector sent to instance 0x78e8de70
teminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException reason NSFaultingMutableSet managedObjectConext unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e8de70

Comment: `description` isn't a great name to use for a relationship because NSManagedObject is a subclass of NSObject which already has a `description` property. If you're playing around with core data to learn it maybe model something more specific (modeling people e.g. 'person' with 'mother', 'father', 'children' etc might be a good topic to model)

Comment: Oh my god I figured it out. For some reason even though I created the ,swift files from the NSManageObject subclass action available from the editor tab it was setting the primary as nsset but the secondary as nsset as well even though it was a one way. I changed it to a instance of the primary and all is well. Thank you for point this out to me!

Comment: I am unsure why core data made it a NSSet as it has never been set as a to many relationship it has always been to one.

Comment: Glad you got it working! FWIW before Xcode 7 I'd just write the NSManagedObject subclasses manually instead of using the generator, but in the latest Xcode betas I've switched to using the automatic generation.

Comment: Should I even answer this or leave it open?

Comment: Nah, I wouldn't accept this as an answer, I probably should have added my suggestions as comments to your question instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Always check core data subclasses after you have them created automatically by Core Data. Sometimes the setup is incorrect as was the case with my problem.